# Using RSpec API Documentation Generator, can I pretty print the request body JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-api-documentation

I'm using the [RSpec API Documentation Generator Gem](https://github.com/zipmark/rspec_api_documentation) for my rails app, and when I generate the docs, the request body (JSON format) is formatted like so:

```
{"user":{"email":"person1@example.com","password":"z5x6c7v8!@!"}}
```

is there a way to pretty print it similar to the following?

```
{
    "user": {
        "email":"person1@example.com",
        "password":"password"
    }
}
```

I can't seem to find any configuration options to do so. I am using both of the following headers:

```
header 'Content-Type', 'application/json'
header 'Accept', 'application/json'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
RspecApiDocumentation.configure do |config|
  config.request_body_formatter = proc do |params|
    JSON.pretty_generate(params)
  end
end
```